# Unsure Whether PCB Components Are Leaking

Tags: capacitor, pcb, repair

I am having problems with my air conditioner as it does not seem to be able to cool the room well. The fan seems to be a bit slow, so I opened the AC and check the PCB as some tutorials on the internet suggested.

It is then I found something unusual on the PCB. Some components seem  to be wrapped around white matter.

[image]

[image]

I wonder whether those are normally there (like a glue)? Or does it indicates that those components are leaking and need to be changed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome. I am going to take a guess and say that some parts look fried extra crispy. Please note that questions about repairing consumer products is off-limits on this site.

Comment: Might also be just dirt that is slightly conductive which might interfere with the operation of the device. Maybe try cleaning the board with some compressed air.

Comment: Needs a good clean to get rid of that black dust. Probably the fan does too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to EE.SE!

That's just white glue to hold the components in place and survive vibration during shipping and use of the product. Perhaps there is electrolytic leakage in the second image, top left corner where it says IC01, coming from the blue capacitor just right to IC01. Can't tell for sure in the image. If you are up for it, unsolder the capacitor, clean the PCB and solder in a new capacitor with the same capacity and voltage rating and note the correct polarity.

Look for bulging electrolytic capacitors and burn marks in general.